# How would one restore missing PE headers?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, portable-executable, ida

I have a binary file which once was a valid PE executable, but all the headers were erased (DOS-header, PE-header and sections table). I managed to guess that one section is `.text` since if converted to asm in IDA it shows some valid asm code. `.rdata` was easy to find as well since it contains some strings which correspond to program's logic. But no further progress. I guess I'm not the first one to stumble upon this problem and there are tools/methods to generate PE headers. Any suggestions?

Comment: download the sources + recompile? (I mean, after the obvious backup restoration option)  (There are only two categories of data: 1) with working backup 2) lost  (and some temporary states between, with high volatility toward one of the two))

Comment: The first question is: What kind of file format do you have? Only the plain raw memory content at a certain address without any headers or another file format with headers? You cannot exactly restore the PE headers. However you might be able to create "simplified" PE headers for the file. However depending on what you want to do with the file (e.g. execute it, pass the file to some tool, ...) a different level of "simplification" is required. Therefore the second question: What do you want to do with the restored file?

Comment: @Ped7g I don't have sources, unfortunately.

Comment: This is one of those questions, I'm afraid, where if you're asking it, you're not even close to appreciating the vast complexity of the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have some problem that you couldn't fix

- the entry point ( where the binary begin)
- the relocation (but you can fix the base adress to skip it)
- the base adress (but in general it is always the same just need to know if it x86 or x64)
- the library used it and the extern functions
- perhaps the resourse for instance py2exe create a resource for the python bytecode
- and last things bu certainly some other if you have a tls fls in the binary

Comment: You might have some luck finding the entry point by looking at the disassembly.  It's a good guess that it's in some boilerplate CRT code, you can look at the entry points in other executables and look for the same code in your headerless one.

Comment: Yes it’s a good idea but you should compile with different compiler and compare it. Each compiler have own CRT